# PHP Retrieve value from array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

How do I retrieve the date values from the following array?  Actually, want I want to do is loop through this array, and create a table cell for each of the date values.  Thanks,

```
Array
(
    [2011-11-18 00:00:00] => 3
    [2011-11-22 00:00:00] => 2
)
```

Comment: That is not a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code to iterate over the array :

```
foreach($yourarray as $key => $value){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$key.'</td>'; //will print "2011-11-18 00:00:00"
    echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>'; //will print "3"
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

You should read about the [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) construct and the [`Array`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) data type.

Answer (score 2):

See array_keys() documentation

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: +1 Although you weren't acknowledged, this seems to be exactly what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to loop, try:

```
// assuming variable is named $array
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    echo "Key: ".$k.", Value: ".$v."<br />\n";
    // or whatever it is you want with them.
}
```